# How can I keep the order of an ordered hashtable after remote session?

Tags: powershell, session, hashtable, ordereddictionary

I invoke a scriptblock of a ServerObject in a remote session. In the scriptblock I create a hashtable and save it in the ServerObject. At the end of the scriptblock the order is correct, after the session the items are in the wrong order.

```
$Serv = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$Serv | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Cn -Value Computername
$Serv | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Inf -Value ""

function getInf (){

  $Inf = [ordered]@{
    SiteConfig = "a";
    BrokerController = "b";
    AdminRoles = "c";       
  }
  $Serv.Inf = $Inf
}

getInf

$ServResult = Invoke-Command -Cn $Serv.Cn -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
  param($Serv)
  Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create($Serv.getInf)) 
  $Serv
}-ArgumentList $Serv
Remove-PSSession -ComputerName $Serv.Cn
$ServResult.Inf
```

Comment: It may be Clixml serialization issue - https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/771721

Comment: I didn't type it from memory. The same code is in my script (the scriptblock and the session are in two different places), but I won't post my 1330 lines of code, just to post some working code. Have you some concrete question?

Comment: @Temerita please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @alroc I changed the example a little bit, so that it is messy but executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$Inf.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property name